# Filtering discrepancies in duplicate measurements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset with the following problem.
Sometimes, a temperature sensor would return duplicate readings at the exact same minute, where sometimes 1 of 2 of the duplicates is "reasonable" and the other is slightly off.
For example:

```
    TEMP   TIME
1   24.5   4/1/18 2:00
2   24.7   4/1/18 2:00 
3   24.6   4/1/18 2:05
4   28.3   4/1/18 2:05
5   24.3   4/1/18 2:10
6   24.5   4/1/18 2:10
7   26.5   4/1/18 2:15
8   24.4   4/1/18 2:15
9   24.7   4/1/18 2:20
10  22.0   4/1/18 2:20
```

Line 5, 7 & 10 are readings that are to be removed as they are too high or low (doesn't make sense that within 5 minutes it will rise and drop more than a degree in a relatively stable environment).

The goal at the end with this dataset is to "average" the similar values (such as in line 1 & 2) and just remove the lines that are too extreme (such as line 5 & 7) from the dataset entirely.

Currently my idea to formulate this is to look at a previously obtained row, and if one of the 2 duplicates is +/- 0.5 degree, to mark in a 3rd column with TRUE so I can filter out all the TRUE values in the end. I'm not sure how to communicate within the if statement that I'm looking for a + OR - 0.5 of a previous number however. Does anyone know?

Comment: Absolute value of difference greater than limit. `ABS(A - B) > limit`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a google sheet example that does what you want:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Va9RjSeulOfVTd-0b4EM4azbUkYUb22jXNc_EcafUO8/edit?usp=sharing

What I did:

- Calculate a column of a 3-item running average of the data using "=AVERAGE(B3:B1)"
- Filter the list using "=IF(ABS(B2-C2) < 1, B2, )"
- Calculate the average of the filtered list

The use of Absolute Value is what provides "+ OR -" that you were looking for. It is saying if the distance between two numbers is too much, then don't include the term.

Answer (score 0):

So, A Simple Solution came to my mind. Follow the Following steps given below:

1. Convert Data to Table
2. Add a 4th column at the last
3. Enter the formula "Current Value - Previous Value"
4. Filter the Column with high difference values
5. Delete those rows of filtered data and you'll be left with Normal Values
   Here's the ref. Image
   [image: Delete High Values]

Answer (score 0):

Or If you want to consider the Same time difference only then do the following:

1. Convert your data to Table
2. Add 4th column at the end of table
3. Writhe the Following Formula to 4th Column
    IF(Current_Time = Previous_Time, Current_Temp-Previous_Temp,"")
4. Filter and Delete the Data with high Difference
   See the following Image:

[image: Example 2]